# How to assign multiple variables from a vector in c++?

Tags: c++

In python, we can assign multiple variables from an iterable. Like this

```
timeA = (10, 45, 11)
hrs, min, sec = timeA
```

Is there a way to do this in C++ with vectors, or any container(like `std::pair`) for that matter.

Expected this to work, but it did not.

```
vector<int> timeA {10, 45, 11};
int hrs, min, sec;
{hrs, min, sec} = timeA;
```

Comment: This is worth a read: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/structured_binding You're on the right lines.

Comment: @TonyTannous Yes, it doesn't work for vectors. So I don't think structured binding can be used.